# Facial capture from webcam

Tags: motion-detection

Hi I´m trying to create a robust facial capture system, which detects facial expressions, like blinks simles,etc, so the it can be translated into an animated model. 
I have no idea where to start but I´m looking for some kind of c++ or java library to code this program.
The idea is that the video has to come from a webcam.
Thx alot

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it myself, but I know several people who've used [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) for this sort of thing.